# Is there a way to search for files by hash value?

Tags: search, file-search, hashing, content-addressable-storage

Is there a way I can have a hash value as input when searching for files and a complete list of files and their locations as output?

This could be helpful when trying to pin point file duplicates. I often times find myself in situations where I have a bunch of files that I know I already have stored in some location but I don't know where. They are essentially duplicates.

For instance, I could have a bunch of files on a portable hard drive, and also hard copies of those files on the internal hard drive of a desktop computer... but I'm not sure of the location! Now if the files are not renamed, I could do a file name search to try to locate the hard copy on the desktop. I could then compare them side by side and in case they are the same I could delete the copy I have on the portable hard drive. But if the files have been renamed on either one of the hard drives this would probably not work (depending on how much the new names differ from the original).

If a file is renamed, but not edited, I could calculate its hash value, e.g. SHA1 value is `74e7432df4a66f246b5214d60b190b67e2f6ce52`. I would then like to have this value as input when searching for files and have the operating system search through a given directory or the entire file system for files with this exact SHA1 hash value and output a complete list of locations where these files are stored.

I'm using Windows, but I am generally interested in knowing how something like this could be achieved, regardless of operating system.

Comment: Unless the file system keeps a table of hashes (most don't) you need to calculate those as part of the search. I would rather use a program that does this for you–it will likely use hashes internally as one mechanism to compare files–than make your own solution. If you do make your own solution, I'd recommend using something like md5 for the hashing. While not cryptographically secure, it's faster than SHA* and provides good enough entropy for the application, for files not intentionally forged to create collisions.

Comment: Hashing a file will rarely be faster than comparing the data in two files (most will fail fairly quickly)

Comment: If hashing is not a good option, then by what other means can I uniquely identify a file?

Comment: Approximately, how long will it take to hash 60 GiB in 135000 files? This is the entire content of my Users folder. Is there any upper limit on how big files I can hash? I know that small files are hashed fairly quickly, but the big ones might take several minutes to hash.

Answer (score 3):

Linux example:

```
hash='74e7432df4a66f246b5214d60b190b67e2f6ce52'
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
   sha1sum "$2" | cut -f 1 -d " " | sed "s|^\\\\||" | grep -Eqi "$1"
' find-sh "$hash" {} \; -print
```

This code is more complex than you would think it should be because:

- it is intended to correctly handle filenames with spaces, newlines, backslashes, quotations, special characters etc. (change `-print` to `-print0` to parse them further);
- it is intended to accept hash(es) as regex (compatible with `grep -E` i.e. `egrep`),
  e.g. `'^00|00$'` will match if the file hash starts or ends with `00`; a more practical example is searching by many hashes at once: `'74…|a9…|…|…|…'` (ellipses for brevity, use full hashes).

You can use other `*sum` tools with compatible interface (e.g. `md5sum`).

Comment: Why do you need to pipe hash to the command and read it with `read`?

Comment: @akostadinov Good question. I don't remember what I was thinking at the time, but now I think I don't need to `read`. I'm going to rebuild the code.

Comment: Maybe it can become simpler if `grep` looks for `^$1\s`, that would allow skipping `cut` and `sed`. Also it will be more efficient to search by existing file. So that first we can search for files matching exact size and calculate checksum only for them. Otherwise it takes a lot of time.

Comment: on linux or wsl for linux, and possibly with native windows versions as well: sudo time catcli --catalog tmp.catcli --hash  index homedir /tmp; cat tmp.catcli | jq -r '.. | arrays | .[] | select(.md5=="06a30d881326d8473d1691ed071639e2")'; catcli --catalog tmp.catcli tree | fgrep -i 06a30d881326d8473d1691ed071639e2
Separe commands at semicolon.  1st builds JSON index with md5 hashes;  2nd command will show matches with path as JSON, 3rd searches and just shows filename/hash.  pip3 install catcli; apt-get install jq

Answer (score 2):

If you have PowerShell v.4.0 or higher, you can use the command:

```
Get-ChildItem _search_location_ -Recurse | Get-FileHash | 
Where-Object hash -eq (Get-FileHash _search_file_).hash | Select path
```

Where `_search_location_` is folder or disk where you want to search for a duplicate and `_search_file_` is a file that has a duplicate somewhere. You can put this command in a loop to search for several files or add `| Remove-Item` at the end of the line to automatically delete duplicates.

Also note that this command is suitable for small search folders only - it will take a lot of time if your search location has thousands of files (like a whole HDD).

Answer (score 1):

This is an intriguing question.  I have been using a tool called fdupes to accomplish something similar.  Fdupes will recursively search through directories and compare every file with every other file.  First it compares size, and if the sizes are identical then it creates hashes of the files and compares that, if the hashes are the same then in actually goes through each file byte by byte and compares it.

When if finds all the files that are truly identical you can have it do several things.  I have it delete the duplicate and create a hardlink in it's place (thus saving me HDD space), although you can have it simply output the locations of the duplicate files and not do anything with them.  This is the scenario you are asking about.

Some downsides with fdupes are that as far as I know it's Linux only, and since it compares every file to every other file it takes quite a bit of I/O and time to run.  It does not "search" for a file per say, but it would list all the files that have an identical hash.

I would highly recommend it and I set it to run in a cron job every day so that I never have any unnecessary duplicates of my data (it excludes my backups of course).

[Fdupes Source Page](http://code.google.com/p/fdupes/)

Answer (score 1):

I like to use simple tools that I happen to already have so here is a way to do that with Windows PowerShell (so it obviously only works on windows). It is actually a small edit to Alex K's answer however the question was how to search using hashes, whereas his answer searched for a copy of a specific file.

```
Get-ChildItem "_search_location_" -Recurse | Get-FileHash | Where-Object hash -eq _hash_here_ | Select path
```

Simply replace `_search_location_` with what directory you wish to search and replace `_hash_here_` with the hash of the file you wish to find.

Comment: Please edit your answer instead of posting a second one. While you do mention it's a slight variation you're missing any information on what you changed or why it makes it better.

Answer (score 1):

[Voidtools Everything 1.5 (Alpha)](https://www.voidtools.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=9787) search tool for Windows has an option to add a column of various hashes, such as CRC-32, CRC-64, MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256 for each file.

[image]

You can then search for a particular hash as well, for example `md5:71E..`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for an MD5 algorithm:

```
Get-ChildItem "_search_location_" -Recurse | Get-FileHash -Algorithm MD5 | Where-Object hash -eq _hash_here_ | Select path
```

Replace `_search_location_` with what directory you wish to search and replace `_hash_here_` with the hash of the file you wish to find.

If you want to search for a hash besides the sha256 hash you add `-Algorithm _algorithm_` after `Get-FileHash` where `_algorithm_` is the chosen algorithm.

Beware that this requires PowerShell 4.0 and will recalculate every hash for every file for every search!

Answer (score -1):

There's a tool ($) called [FileLocator Pro](http://mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro) that can search by file hash (SHA-x or MD5).

Excerpt from this page:
http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/help/en/advanced_criteria.htm

> Note: If the expression type is set to 'File Hash' then the containing
>   text box can include a comma separated list of hash values or a
>   pointer to a file containing a list of hash values, e.g.
>
> 5A9C9B42A16F5E1985B7B0A019114C7A,675C9B42A16F5E1985B7B0A019114C7A
>
> or,
>
> =c:\FileHashTable.txt
>
> The actual algorithms used to calculate the hash, e.g. SHA1, MD5, are
>   specified in the Options tab.